# Different dependencies require different sdk versions

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a project where I have two dependencies defined in my build.gradle.

However, one requires an compilesdkversion of 22 and the other of 23. Naturally when I compile with each sdk version I get different errors depending on the incorrect library.

Is there a way round this?

the dependencies I am using are

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
compile 'com.javon.parserecyclerviewadapter:parserecyclerviewadapter:1.0.7'
```

EDIT:
If I opt for version 23 as suggested in the comments I get the build error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                                  ^
symbol:   class Configuration
location: class Parse
```

and

```
Error:(54, 39) error: cannot find symbol class Configuration
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Set `compileSdkVersion` of 23 -- always choose the higher one. Then, ask a separate question where you explain the errors that you are getting, and perhaps people here can help you work through those errors.

Comment: You also need to decide on a minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the com.javon.parserecycleradapter. I ended up deciding not to use it and created my own adapated use use with a recyclerview, that way compilining with 23 and 22 work.